# How can I prevent new elements overwriting existing elements in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geolocation

I'm playing with [mbostock's example of using d3.js with google maps](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711#stations.json), trying to adapt it with a 2d array of my own data.

My data is an array of objects, each of which has a timestamp and an array of GeoCoordinates, `Coordinates`.

```
[{"TimeStamp":"2014-06-18T22:18:07+04:30","Coordinates":[{"Latitude":40.416775,"Longitude":-3.70379},{"Latitude":40.415793,"Longitude":-3.707424},{"Latitude":40.414142,"Longitude":-3.707982}]}
,{"TimeStamp":"2014-06-18T22:23:07+04:30","Coordinates":[{"Latitude":40.411365,"Longitude":-3.708712},{"Latitude":40.411986,"Longitude":-3.705021},{"Latitude":40.406774,"Longitude":-3.711716}]}
,{"TimeStamp":"2014-06-18T22:28:07+04:30","Coordinates":[{"Latitude":40.401365,"Longitude":-3.720449},{"Latitude":40.388455,"Longitude":-3.731843},{"Latitude":40.383568,"Longitude":-3.738881}]}]
```

I couldn't find a way to iterate through all Coordinate objects, so added a for loop for each element of first level array:

```
// Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {
        var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;
        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
              .data(data[i].Coordinates)
              .each(transform) // update existing markers
              .enter()
              .append("svg:svg")
              .each(transform)
              .attr("class", "marker");

            // Add a circle.
            marker.append("svg:circle")
              .attr("r", 4.5)
              .attr("cx", padding)
              .attr("cy", padding);

            // Add a label.
            marker.append("svg:text")
              .attr("x", padding + 7)
              .attr("y", padding)
              .attr("dy", ".31em")
              .text(function(d, i){
                    return i;
                    });
        }

        function transform(d) {
                d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.Latitude, d.Longitude);
                d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                return d3.select(this)
                    .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
        }
    };
};
```

However, d3 overwrites marker svg elements in each iteration and shows only 3 markers instead of 9 in this case.

Why is that?

Comment: You don't need a loop here. Use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Selection is about DOM parts not my data array.

Comment: Well yes? You have nested data and should have nested DOM elements to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question directly, d3 is overwriting the SVG elements on each loop because they are indexed by their position in the array. You must provide an id function, which is the second parameter to the `data()` function. Code to follow.

The nested selections is not a good fit for this scenario because you don't want nested html, for the reason pointed out in the linked code: "We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?". So we do want to use a for loop at some point.

Note also that it is only the 'enter phase' that needs to go in the for loop, though it shouldn't make much difference if you put the rendering in there also.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.411365, -3.708712),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

 // Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
d3.json("soQuest.json", function(data) {
  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
      .attr("class", "stations");

    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {
      var projection = this.getProjection(),
        padding = 10,
        marker;


      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
          .data(data[i].Coordinates, function(d, index){
            return data[i].TimeStamp + index + d.Latitude + d.Longitude;
          })
          .enter().append("svg");
      }

      marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
        .each(transform) // update existing markers
      .attr("class", "marker");

      // Add a circle.
      marker.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .attr("cx", padding)
        .attr("cy", padding);

      // Add a label.
      marker.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", padding + 7)
        .attr("y", padding)
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return "MARKER"; //d.key;
        });

      function transform(d) {
        d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.Latitude, d.Longitude);
        d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
        return d3.select(this)
          .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
          .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
      }
    };
  };

  // Bind our overlay to the map…
  overlay.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: According to your explanations and my sample data, the map function you provided won't work neither because there is some points with the same lat/long.

Comment: Hi SAM, [here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r0IkTCEQTMwi4eac8UIu). It works for the data you provided, but if you have two markers on the same coordinates you will need to include something else in the id to make them unique. That should not be too much of a challenge.

Comment: OK, have changed the id function so it's guaranteed to return a unique id, but it would look much nicer if your markers had a unique property that could be used instead. Now have I answered the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try defining the variable `marker` outside the for loop. Let me know if that solves the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is just flatten the array,

```
var flat_data = [];

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
   for (var j=0; j<data[i].length; j++){
       flat_data.push(data[i][j])
   }
}
```

Then skip your for loop and just do

```
var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {
        var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;

        var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
           .data(flat_data)
           .each(transform) // update existing markers
           .enter()
           .append("svg:svg")
           .each(transform)
           .attr("class", "marker");

        // Add a circle.
        marker.append("svg:circle")
           .attr("r", 4.5)
           .attr("cx", padding)
           .attr("cy", padding);

        // Add a label.
        marker.append("svg:text")
           .attr("x", padding + 7)
           .attr("y", padding)
           .attr("dy", ".31em")
           .text(function(d, i){
              return i;
           });
        }

    function transform(d) {
        d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.Latitude, d.Longitude);
        d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
           return d3.select(this)
              .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
              .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Flattening the array is not a good choice since accessing timestamps related to each element needs dirty work and makes code hard to read.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to backfill that data into the flattened array.